# c++ - iterating through a map of 3 elements

Tags: c++, syntax, iterator, scope-resolution

I'm very new to the use of STL containers in C++.

I have a map of 3 elements (2 strings as a pair - acting as the key, and an int acting as the value.)

```
map<pair<string, string>, int> wordpairs;
```

But when I try to iterate through it like this:

```
  for (map<pair<string, string>, int> iterator i = wordpairs.begin(); i != wordpairs.end(); i++) {
      cout << i->first << " " << i->second << "\n";
    }
```

the compiler is throwing errors:

```
     error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
         for (map<pair<string, string>, int> iterator i = wordpairs.begin(); i != wordpairs.
                                                      ^
    error: name lookup of ‘i’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping [-fpermissive]
    a7a.cpp:46:50: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)

   error: cannot convert ‘std::map<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, int> >}’ to ‘int’ in assignment
         for (map<pair<string, string>, int> iterator i = wordpairs.begin(); i != wordpairs.
                                                        ^
    error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘std::map<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, int> >}’)
         for (map<pair<string, string>, int> iterator i = wordpairs.begin(); i != wordpairs.
                                                                               ^    

    error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
     pair<string, string>, int> iterator i = wordpairs.begin(); i != wordpairs.end(); i++) {
                                                                                    ^
   error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
     pair<string, string>, int> iterator i = wordpairs.begin(); i != wordpairs.end(); i++) {
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here - this should be a simple fix though.

Comment: shouldn't it be map<pair<string, string>, int>::iterator i ?? map<pair<string, string>, int> iterator i does not makes sense ... you are declaring two variable at once (iterator and i )

Comment: Using spaces where you need colons.

Comment: Thanks guys! That solved the problem!

Comment: But now I have another problem: `error: no match for ‘operator<<’ ` at the line: `cout << i->first << " " << i->second << "\n";`
This is unrelated to the original question though, I assume.

Comment: @RockAndaHardPlace its because `i->first` is a pair<string, string> .. So how would you print a pair? see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228994/how-to-print-a-type-vectorpairchar-int-to-screen-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You got the type wrong (you used spaces instead of `::`).
2. Map iterator gives you a key value pair -- and your key is a pair! So you have a pair with a pair as a member. Here's an example that does roughly what you want to do.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <map>
   #include <string>
   #include <utility>
   using namespace std;

   int main() {
     pair<string, string> my_key("To", "Be");
     map<pair<string, string>, int> wordpairs { { {"Hello", "World"}, 33} };
     for (const auto& kv : wordpairs) {
       cout << kv.first.first << ", " 
            << kv.first.second << static_cast<char>(kv.second);
     }
     return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: I did this: `cout << i.first.first << " " << i.first.second << "\n" << static_cast<char>(kv.second);` but it is throwing errors. Also, not sure why we're using: `static_cast<char>(kv.second)`

Comment: If you're using an iterator, remember that they act like pointers. so instead of `i.first.first` you should use `i->first.first`. Also, the `static_cast<char>(....)` was to be cute -- run my example through a C++11 compiler and see what the ensuing program does =).

Comment: I'm getting a weird character with binary digits on the output lol.

Comment: You're probably doing `kv.second` instead of `kv->second`.

Comment: No I think it might have something to do with the `static_cast<char>(....)`... I am getting the correct output with the strings themselves, but additional characters with them

Answer (score 2):

You forgot :: before iterator.
You can also use the auto keyword:

```
for (auto i = wordpairs.begin(); i != wordpairs.end(); ++i) {
  cout << i->first << " " << i->second << "\n";
}
```

or simply using the range-based for loop:

```
for (auto& i : wordpairs) {
  cout << i->first << " " << i->second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Djerdjer! That solves this issue, but now I have another problem: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ at the line: cout << i->first << " " << i->second << "\n"; This is unrelated to the original question though, I assume.

Comment: Is the <string> header included in your program?

Comment: Yes it is included.

Comment: Are you using std::string? (or using namespace std)

Comment: Yes I am indeed

Comment: Which syntax are you using, auto or range-based for loop? I think it will be easier to figure out the problem if you can share your code.

Comment: Range based for loop... I think I mentioned the for loop in the original question write-up. If that's not what you're looking for, I can edit the original question.

Comment: Ah I just realized that your map key is a pair, so you need print the pair (cout << i-> first.first << " " << i ->first.second << i->second << "\n";